# Loading php file inside iframe on page load jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I want to load some file.php inside iframe on page load and then with ref load clicked one. My code is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".divlink").click(function(){
     $("#content").attr("src" , $(this).attr("ref"));});});
```

and my ref is

```
<a href="#" ref="profile.php" class="divlink" ><div id="links">Profile</div></a>
```

and my iframe is

```
<iframe style="border: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="content"></iframe>
```

So everything is working great, but when I load page its empty and when I click on the some link it shows me file in iframe. Now my question is what should I add to load basic page into frame on page load and change it when I click? Thanks

Comment: You could just set a source link for the iframe and change it when one clicks on a button...

Comment: Thanks it worked !!! I never thought about adding src to iframe. My mistake! THanks